# How to chart the values of two columns in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I simply want to compare two totals of two columns in my dataframe using a seaborn bar chart, but I think I'm doing it really inefficiently.  There has to be a better way to do this.

Here is how i'm summing my two columns I want to compare the totals of.

```
total_member_paid = alee_merge_df['Total_Member_Paid'].sum()
total_plan_paid = alee_merge_df['Total_Plan_Paid'].sum()
```

Then, I'm making a dataframe to plot the values.  I wanted the two column names on the x axis, and their totals on the Y axis, but i'm not seeing an easy way to do this.

Here's the dataframe I have created:

```
total_rx_spend_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Total_Member_Paid', 'Total_Plan_Paid'])
total_rx_spend_df.at[0, 'Total_Member_Paid'] = total_member_paid
total_rx_spend_df.at[0, 'Total_Plan_Paid'] = total_plan_paid
```

The data looks like this:

```
    Total_Member_Paid   Total_Plan_Paid
0   639713              7.48757e+06
```

I wanted to have two bars, with the column names on the X axis and their totals on the Y. Should I be pivoting this data so the column names are a part of the data?  This seems like it should be easy, but I can't seem to find anything on Google trying to do the same thing.

EDIT: I was able to get pretty close to what I was looking for, but using pandas:

```
total_rx_spend_df[['Total_Member_Paid','Total_Plan_Paid']].plot(kind='bar')
```

Is there a way to do this, but in seaborn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to get what I was looking for by applying melt to my dataframe:

```
total_rx_spend_melt = pd.melt(total_rx_spend_df)
```

This game me a dataframe looking like this:

```
    variable            value
0   Total_Member_Paid   639713
1   Total_Plan_Paid     7.48757e+06
```

Then the plot came out how I wanted using a simple bar graph.

```
sns.barplot(x='variable', y = 'value', data = total_rx_spend_melt)
```